# how to find recursive function name list in a c++ project

Tags: c, recursion, scripting

I want to find out all recursive functions's name in a c++ project which have many files.
Is there any IDE or scripts can do this?

Comment: run regex over all files should do the job

Comment: I am not sure a regex would help there...

Comment: By recursive you mean those that call themselves directly, or also those that are re-entered through a call chain? Because the first is quite easy to cook up, the second one requires quite a bit more work (a static code analysis tool can build a call graph which you can examine for cycles).

Comment: C or C++? Decide.

Comment: I  just want to find the easy one-- call themselves directly

Comment: You may want to create the cross reference links table with crange, and then process it with awk.

Comment: You had better used a naming convention to identify recursive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as easy as others may think.

1. A function call can be inside a double-quoted string or a comment, so you may want to remove these.  When removing strings (or maybe replacing them by the word 0STRING), you should search for matching double quote. Be aware of `\\` and `\"` tokens.
2. Even after you removed all these, finding function start, end, and call can be a challenge. Take into account template functions, for example.  Also, f(a b){g(b);} is not neccessarily a function, if there is a macro f.  Maybe you want to take this to account too.
3. Also:

The following function is recursive

```
class A {
    F(int x) {
        // ...
        A::F(y);
    }
}
```

while the following is not

```
class A {
    F(int x) {
        // ...
        B::F(y);
    }
}
```

Same about namespaces.  Namespace qualifier, like class qualifier, may or may not make the function non-recursive.

You may want to create the cross reference links table with crange, and then process it with awk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you'd have to write your own script for this, and it's not quite trivial.  You need to recognize the start and end of a function as well as a function call.  That part isn't awful.  However, you need to maintain a stack of nested functions, so you always know the innermost function at this parsing point.  Whenever you find a call to the innermost function, you report that you've found recursion.

The minorly tricky case is something like this:

```
int func_a() {
    ...
    int func_b() {
        ...
        result = func_a()
    }

    recur = func_a()
```

The first call is not recursive; the second one is.  The nesting can get deeper -- you have to count braces *outside* of literal strings -- add 1 for a left brace, subtract one for a right brace, and check the total for the "brace-nesting" number of the innermost function on your stack.

Does that help move you toward a solution?